# Не отвечает на команду с упоминанием, vkbottle

Tags: python, бот

Написал код для бота, с командой "Расписание", на команду он отвечает в беседе, но когда нажимаю на кнопку, идет упоминание бота + команда, на упоминание он не отвечает ,а на обычное сообщение отвечает.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import vkbottle
from vkbottle.bot import Bot, Message
from vkbottle import keyboard, KeyboardButtonColor, Text, OpenLink, Location, EMPTY_KEYBOARD
from vkbottle.tools.dev_tools.keyboard.button import KeyboardButton
from vkbottle.tools.dev_tools.keyboard.keyboard import Keyboard
from settiings import settings, token

bot = Bot(token=token)

@bot.on.chat_message(text=["Расписание", "@for10arsp Расписание"])
async def handler(message: Message):
    keyboard = Keyboard()

    Keyboard(inline=True)

    keyboard.add(Text("Расписание"), color=KeyboardButtonColor.SECONDARY)
    await message.answer(f'Сейчас расписания нет.', keyboard=keyboard)

bot.run_forever()
```

Есть какая то возможность пофиксить?

Answer (score 1):

Есть два способа решить данную проблему:

#### Передача `payload` при нажатии на кнопку

Кнопки клавиатуры [позволяют](https://vk.com/dev/bots_docs_3?f=4.2.%20%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85,) передавать полезную нагрузку (`payload`), которую потом можно считывать при получении сообщения:

```py
from vkbottle import Bot, Message, Keyboard, Text

bot = Bot("token")

@bot.on.message(payload={"command": 42})
async def button_handler(m: Message):
    await m.answer("Кнопка была нажата")

@bot.on.message()  # handler для отправки клавиатуры
async def start_handler(m: Message):
    keyboard = Keyboard()
    keyboard.add(Text("Test button", payload={"command": 42}))
    await m.answer(
        "Клавиатура",
        keyboard=keyboard.get_json()
    )
```

У vkbottle есть целых [три правила (`rules`)](https://github.com/vkbottle/vkbottle/blob/da5553623a1591e5bf9d4df77c42395c08430bb2/vkbottle/dispatch/rules/bot.py#L246,) для обработки payload. `payload` для точной проверки, `payload_contains` для проверки отдельных элементов (ключ - значение), и `payload_map` для проверки на типы (ключ - тип значения).

#### Правильная обработка упоминания сообщества

Все упоминания ВКонтакте (пользователя или сообщества) меняются в сообщение формата `[id|текст]` (что позволяет делать ссылки на любые ресурсы внутри ВКонтакте). Тогда нужно немного поменять текст: `@bot.on.chat_message(text=["Расписание", "[club206902229|@for10arsp] Расписание"])`

---

Самый правильный способ будет первый, поскольку, если вы смените короткий адрес сообщества или переместите бота в другое сообщество, то, во втором случае, вам придётся меня все правила, в которых используется упоминание сообщества.